# Asp.Net Mvc Identity&Owin true way for Two-Factor authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, owin-middleware

I am new using two-factor authentication and have problems.Error is raising after sms code verify button click.I am registering and then entering the sms code  the **error** is,

> The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.

I am **using**

Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core v2.2.2

Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin v2.2.2

I am trying to use SMS authentication for every login.In my controller is the order of methods is like this,

For register :

```
await UserManager.CheckUserDuplicate(user);
await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, FrSettings.Settings.DefaultRole);
await UserManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user.Id, true);

string code = await UserManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(user.Id, user.CepNo);

var message = new IdentityMessage
                            {
                                Destination = user.CepNo,
                                Body = SystemMessage.SmsMessage + code
                            };

                            SignInStatus resultSignIn = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, false, false);
                            switch (resultSignIn)
                            {
                                case SignInStatus.Success:
                                    await UserManager.SmsService.SendAsync(message);
                                    break;
                                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                                    break;
                                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                                    await UserManager.SmsService.SendAsync(message);
                                    break;
                                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                            }
```

And for login :

```
await UserManager.ChangePhoneNumberAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), User.Name(), model.SmsCode);
```

My login is not finished but my first method is this.Please do not avoid to make suggestions about login correctly and secure.

If need more info about project I can update!.

**UPDATE INFO 1** :

After login or register I am not using redirect.I am using ajax in one page for all account actions.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224300/anti-forgery-token-was-meant-for-a-different-claims-based-user) helps.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but not info for me :/