# Antiforgery exception (Provided antiforgery token meant for a different claims-based user) on post method, when user is authenticated

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-2.2, antiforgerytoken

I am using **ASP.NET Core 2.2** with **AspNetCore.Authentication**.

I am trying to use `Post` call in my `cshtml` _Layout's view component's form:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SearchResults" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-antiforgery="true" novalidate>

(...)

</form>
```

My intetntion is to mask URL with search properties to make web crawling and **scraping** more difficult. My `Post` method is updating static fields of my controller, and redirecting to my Index `Get` method, where are displayed search results:

```
    private static SearchViewModel _searchModel;
    private static string _sortOrder;
    private static int? _pageNumber;

(...)

[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult SearchResults(SearchViewModel searchModel, string sortOrder, int? pageNumber = 1)
        {
            _searchModel = searchModel;
            _sortOrder = sortOrder;
            _pageNumber = pageNumber;

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

And `Get` method signature:

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    //refering to updated fields
}
```

Idea inspired with [this SO reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32007946/12603542).

And Setup.cs identity/authentication setup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
             services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(opts => {
                opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                opts.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null; //disable validation
                opts.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                opts.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddAntiforgery(x => x.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN");
            .Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                //previous cookies not valid
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            });
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
                options.Filters.Add<AuditUserActionFilter>();
            });
            
            (...)
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {
            (...)
            
            app.Use(next => context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path == "/")
                {
                    var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                    context.Response.Cookies.Append("CSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
                }
                return next(context);
            });
            app.UseAuthentication();
        }
    }
```

**I belive that this is a key:** Actually, when I am submitting `Post` form as a guest (not authenticated), everything works fine. But after signing in, on form submit I am receiving an exception:

> Provided antiforgery token meant for a different claims-based user

Also please find below my user authentication process:

```
if (user != null)
                {
                    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

                    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, details.Password, false, false);

                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                            return Redirect(returnUrl);
                        else
                            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Account));
                    }
                    else if (result.IsLockedOut || result.IsNotAllowed)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "You are not allowed to sign in.";
                        return View("Error");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(UserLoginViewModel.Password), "Incorrect password.");
                        return View("Index");
                    }
                }
```

I was trying several approaches from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4953), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224300/anti-forgery-token-was-meant-for-a-different-claims-based-user) with no results. But they are for older versions of ASP.NET Core. I am not sure how I am supposed to update my antiforgery tokens for authenticated user?

Possible reasons of my problem:

1. misunderstanding of Post -> Get form call.
2. not understanding how authentication cookies works in ASP.NET Core authentication.
3. misunderstanding of authentication process in general.

**P.S.**
When I remove

```
options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
```

from:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
                options.Filters.Add<AuditUserActionFilter>();
            });
```

I am able to make `Post` call. But I belive, that it is not any surprise.

**EDIT:**
Because of some reason, when I submit  form from another view (form is in _Layout's view component) than Home/Index (where I display search results), there is no antiforgery exception.

Is it because `HomeController`'s `Index` action is `Get`? After adding `Post / Get` attribute:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet, HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
```

I have same exception as before. After adding:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
```

I am not able to load the view at all, because it is asking for the token.

How to bypass it?

Comment: *But after signing in, on form submit I am receiving an exception*:  Note it was too late to invoke your  `UseAuthentication()`. At least, put it before you invoke the middleware where you access the CSRF token.

Comment: Thank you, actually you helped me to understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **itminus** advice I understood, that I have to move in my `Configure` method my `app.UseAuthentication();` to the top. Also, after reading [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1) I realized, that after using [AddMvc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcservicecollectionextensions.addmvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1) I do not need anymore code refering to `"CSRF-TOKEN"`.

At the end my Startup.cs looks like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
             services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(opts => {
                opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                opts.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null; //disable validation
                opts.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                opts.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            .Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                //previous cookies not valid
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            });
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
                options.Filters.Add<AuditUserActionFilter>();
            });

            (...)
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();

            (...)
        }
    }
```